# How to move a button to an specific x/y position in Kotlin?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

How can I move a button to a specific x/y position on the view with a duration?

the code should look like this:
Button is clicked-> Button moves to x = 50

```
settings.setOnClickListener {
 settings.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the translation methods?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX(float)

If you want to be super fancy you could use animations: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

Alternatively, you could place a hidden button at x = 50 and then hide the original button. (with setVisibility() in Java, Keep in mind that it wouldn't be the same button anymore)

I hope I could help.